# Bottom margin is not working for position relative div

Tags: css

I'm using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay_no-anim) script from W3Schools.

There was some minor modifications acording to my needs.

I added in **.overlay** class an **overflow-y: auto;** because my content is longer and the original example has only a few lines and the scrolling bar is coming handy.

I switched in both **.overlay .closebtn** classes the **position: fixed** to **position: absolute** because like I said the content will be long and the closing button have to be present while scrolling and not fixed only on the top.

The problem is in **.overlay-content** is specified **top: 25%** and if I try to add **bottom: 25%** is not working. If I delete both top and bottom and I use margin-top and magin-bottom is working but is that valid? It's is valid to use margin in conjunction with position:relative?

Comment: Post your code in a fiddle or something. You should decide if you want it at the `top:25%` or at the bottom `bottom:25%`. P.s. Don't use W3Schools.

Comment: try using `bottom` in `px` or `vh`

Answer (score 0):

> It will be work

`.overlay-content{
   z-index: 999;
}`